# SQL Server: SUM amount when date greater than eomonth

Tags: sql-server, date, sum

I have a view that returns [this result](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/16/1461252758-21-04-2016-16-27-37.jpg).

[image]

I want to sum the amounts where `dateValidite` is great then a certain `end of month` (that changes)

For example last day of month is '2016/01/31' so I will sum all the amounts (`MontantAuto`) where `DateValidite > last day of month`

I'm using this query but this sum I get is incorrect

```
select
    a.Monnaie
    , a.Category
    , a.Personne
    , EOMONTH(DATEADD(mm,-1,a.DateValidite)) as Previous
    , sum(b.MontantAuto) As mnt
from 
    olap.tf_autorisation_balance a 
inner join 
    olap.tf_autorisation_balance b  on a.Id = B.Id
where 
    EOMONTH(DATEADD(mm,-1,a.DateValidite)) < b.DateValidite
group by 
    a.Monnaie, a.Category, a.Personne, a.DateValidite
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your request as :

```
where EOMONTH(DATEADD(mm,-1,a.DateValidite)) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), b.DateValidite, 103)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm getting this error message. "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."
"DateValidite" is actually a datetime why do I have to convert it ?